# What to do if the terminal send "apt-key is deprecated"

Tags: apt, wine

I am trying to install wine. Following the commands indicated for Wine installation that I placed with bullets. I received a WARNING stating "apt-key is deprecated". I am not sure what to do here.

Here are the steps I did:

```
yd@yd:~$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
[sudo] password for yd:
yd@yd:~$ wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key 
  sudo apt-key add winehq.key

--2021-06-17 18:04:43--  https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/winehq.key
Resolving dl.winehq.org (dl.winehq.org)... 151.101.194.217, 151.101.130.217, 151.101.66.217, ...
Connecting to dl.winehq.org (dl.winehq.org)|151.101.194.217|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3220 (3.1K) [application/pgp-keys]
Saving to: ‘winehq.key’
winehq.key          100%[===================>]   3.14K  --.-KB/s    in 0s      
2021-06-17 18:04:43 (8.93 MB/s) - ‘winehq.key’ saved [3220/3220]
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK
yd@yd:~$ sudo apt-key add winehq.key
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
OK
```

After this , I am supposed to add two other commands:

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main'
sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

I do not know what to do about this warning message.

1. Should I continue with the last two commands
2. should I deal with the warning message. if yes, how?
3. can I revert the installation command I already did? if yes, how?

Comment: Just curious, but which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: If you're running *focal* or 20.04, why you be wanting to running a command geared for *bionic* or 18.04?  Why aren't you just installing `wine` from default Ubuntu repositories? rather than using what appears to be a build for an older/bionic release in your newer/focal system?  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=wine&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all  You're missing details

Comment: If you are ok with the security implications, you can ignore the warning. It's deprecated but it still works. However there is no need to add a repo to install wine.

Comment: Simple ignore it, its a just warning. If you are installing Wine on 20.04 LTS, then you should have *focal* instead of *bionic* in `'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main'` line.

Comment: Thx for the input. I am new to Linux and Ubuntu. Trying to make sense of your input. Checking https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu , I understand that the "bionic main" was an error. Also, I just use timeshift to restore as I attempted to place remaining commands using focal and received error messages. How do you "just install wine from default Ubuntu repositories"? Does the suggestion "install from default Ubuntu repositories" mean to execute the sequence of commands written on https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to install Wine directly from their repository, and not from Ubuntu's. You only have installed the gpg key, with a warning (not an error).

The easieast path would be to install Wine from Ubuntu's repository (you problably don't need the latest updates). Type on the terminal:

```
sudo apt install wine
```

or

```
sudo apt install wine64
```