# 22.04 apt-key is deprecated - wine64

Tags: apt, wine

I was installing `wine64` because I know that it's useful to install and to run any Windows app, I was following the steps how to install from [this website](https://linuxhint.com/install-use-wine-linux/).

The step that I couldn't continue to complete the installation is:

`$ wget -qO- https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key | sudo apt-key add -`

Output: `Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)). OK`

Could anyone explain me me how to?

Comment: A "Warning" is not a terminating error. It's just a warning. Check whether or not the key was added.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do if the terminal send "apt-key is deprecated"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1346612/what-to-do-if-the-terminal-send-apt-key-is-deprecated)

Comment: @user535733, It's different, I'm looking for the replacement of `sudo apt-key add -`

Comment: Oh, in that case the Search box is your friend: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286545 has several excellent answers addressing "why" and "what to do instead."

Comment: I wrote an answer for "It's different, I'm looking for the replacement of sudo apt-key add -" but you didn't want to follow it as you said it was about wine and not winehq, but yet your link above is about winehq.  `wine` is in the Canonical repos and you don't need to follow any of those instructions.